# Jwt Token audience validation failed when deployed

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I am using ASPNET core 5.0 for both front-end and back-end API. It worked perfectly on the local machine, but I deploy both the front-end and API application it always gives me audience validation failure. here is the code I am using.

```
"Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "RestaurantPortal",
    "Audience": "http://mansoor0786-001-site1.ctempurl.com/",
    "Key": "ASAscethtCVdAQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEDhnGasldjaslkjdleEnGunGWR4Z79AvrtgIjYXhcWZx4OqpvWbsdsdsdSafcV/ZuPw25KbhKWhg1SIXXU2Ad7maaGAk******"
  },
```

I have kept this in appSettings of both front end and API applications. Here is API startup code

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        });
        services.AddAuthentication()
       .AddCookie()
       .AddJwtBearer(config =>
       {
           config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
           {
               ValidIssuer = JwtConfiguration.JWTIssuer,
               ValidAudience = JwtConfiguration.JWTAudience,
               IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtConfiguration.JWTKey)),
               ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
           };
       });
```

Here is the validation I am doing on API end when user wants to login.

```
public bool ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        try
        {
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidIssuer = JwtConfiguration.JWTIssuer,
                ValidAudience = JwtConfiguration.JWTAudience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtConfiguration.JWTKey)),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Locally it works fine but when deploy these both applications it gives me an error and when I try to login it doesn't allow me to login into system. Here are the URL for both API and front-end application. This where I generate token

```
 public string GenerateAccessToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
        {
            var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JwtConfiguration.JWTKey));
            var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: JwtConfiguration.JWTIssuer,
                audience: JwtConfiguration.JWTAudience,
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                signingCredentials: signinCredentials
            );
            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
            return tokenString;
        }
```

In this the configuration gets information from appSettings.json

```
public static class JwtConfiguration
    {
        public static readonly string JWTIssuer = Utils._config["Jwt:Issuer"];
        public static readonly string JWTAudience = Utils._config["Jwt:Audience"];
        public static readonly string JWTKey = Utils._config["Jwt:Key"];
    }
```

This is my response from when I log in the user

```
 if (apiResponseModel != null && apiResponseModel.Data != null && apiResponseModel.Data.Status == 1)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                     {
                        new Claim(AuthKeys.AccessToken, apiResponseModel.Data.AccessToken),
                        new Claim(AuthKeys.RefreshToken, apiResponseModel.Data.RefreshToken)
                     };
                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                      claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                    };
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                      CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                      new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                      authProperties);
                    if (apiResponseModel.Data.RoleName == UserRole.Roles.Customer.GetEnumDescription())
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "dashboard");
                }
```

After that it redirected to dashboard index page where I wrote base controller and added attribute on top of basecontroller which does the following.

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(JWT_Authentication))]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public readonly IOptions<AppSettingDTO> _appSetting;
        protected readonly IUserProfileInfo _userService;
        public readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        protected readonly IHttpNetClientService _apiService;

        public BaseController(IOptions<AppSettingDTO> AppSetting, IHttpNetClientService HttpService, IUserProfileInfo UserInfo, IHttpContextAccessor HttpContext)
        {
            _appSetting = AppSetting;
            _apiService = HttpService;
            _userService = UserInfo;
            _httpContextAccessor = HttpContext;

        }

    }
```

Here is my JWT_Authentication

```
public class JWT_Authentication : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        protected readonly IUserProfileInfo _userService;
        public JWT_Authentication(IHttpContextAccessor HttpContext, IUserProfileInfo UserInfo)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = HttpContext;
            _userService = UserInfo;
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            string actionName = context.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString().ToLower();
            string controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower();

            if (
                controllerName != "account" && actionName != "logout")
            {
                string accessTokens = _userService.GetToken(_httpContextAccessor);               
                if (!_userService.ValidateToken(accessTokens))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(){
                            { "action", "LogOut" },
                            { "controller", "Account" }
                        });
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

> API

http://mansoor00786-001-site1.gtempurl.com/

> Front-End

http://mansoor0786-001-site1.ctempurl.com/

I am calling login API from the front-end application which is also in asp net core 5.0 but it doesn't log me into the dashboard because of validation failure and that is because of the audience.

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite get it, `.AddJwtBearer()` validated the jwt for us already, so why should we need another `ValidateToken()` ? And could you please explain more about the project structure ? Did we have 1 Identity Provider instance, 1 API instance and 1 Web project instance ? Also how do we config them to generate token and a sample jwt would be nice

Comment: Project structure is I have created and API which will be accessed by mobile and also by front end web applications

Comment: anybody with any suggestion or something which can be helpful. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: According to me, there was not enough information for us to help without you you made some update about at least what I think important above. Actually, I don't think the prob was at `audience validation failure`, but potentially on `Issuer`, as they would normally inspect at the `Host` header of the request to decide it, ofcourse, if we doens't re-invent identity provider on our own. Anyway, the block of code on how we generate Jwt token on `identity provider` instance and a sample jwt token would be helpful.

Comment: Hope this code helps you understand what I am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as i saw it, here is some points I spot

> There won't ever be an exception was throw when calling `ValidateToken`

Cause we put it on try catch block, so where does it throw `audience validation failure` ? It cannot be during deployment cause catch block doesn't have logging support anywhere, therefore, it might just be your assumption. And behavior on production state should be always redirect to Login page after logout.

> The way MVC project handle Jwt Token was cumbersome

As we handmade Jwt Token and validate them ourself, such thing as validation failure with the same setting (Issuer, audience,...) should not exists. If that was fine on the client, have faith and logging those setting out from production state.

And for current approach, We can validate Jwt token and restrict them from access our resource fine, but `HttpContext.User` object still be null, therefore Authorization process became mostly, unusable.

Instead, how about consider to write our own Authentication scheme ?

> What might be the problem here ?

```cs
public class JWT_Authentication : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //... Some upper process
        if (!_userService.ValidateToken(accessTokens))
        {
            // Doing something if the jwt invalid ?
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        //... Some below process
    }
}
```

If my block code idea was right, take a look at `string accessTokens = _userService.GetToken(_httpContextAccessor);`, log it out, as there might be a `null` here, due to you passing down a `IHttpContextAccessor`, which was singleton, not a `HttpContext` which scope for each request (localhost would be fine, cause we have only one client).

Comment: ValidateToken always return false in case of exception I have debug the code and it gives me audience issue.

Comment: In case we got locally version of it for debugging, then I'm pretty sure we have a sample jwt token, right ? Check the Jwt itself and the config again to make sure they match(on production environment ofcourse). Beside, the most possible case on production environment was `_userService` part. As I explained above. But I also don't know how `IUserProfileInfo` was implemented along with its lifetime, so I can only made assumption...

Comment: services.AddScoped<IUserProfileInfo, UserProfileInfo>(); Here is the scope of UserProfileInfo

Comment: Injecting `Singleton` instance to a `Scope` instance could lead to ambiguous lifetime. It depend on how the code was implemented, guess we might want to double check that.